# Expectation of unifrom iid r.v. multiplied together

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ be iid uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.

How do we find $E[X_1X_2\cdots X_n]$?

I know how to do it for the case of summation $E[X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n]$, but I am not sure how to do it if we multiplied the random variables. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote iid, which means **independent** identically distributed. The independence implies  that the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations. (The converse is not always true.)  Identically distributed tells us that the product is in fact a power.

**Remark:** The nice thing about sums is that the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations, **whether or not** we have independence.  The expectation of a product is less simple. But under the independence assumption, the expectation behaves as expected.

Comment: Oh, is it as simple as that? so in that case it will be $1/(2)^n$, correct? thanks for the response.

Comment: It is the **product** of the expectations. So it is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: I corrected it, thanks.